# Route torrent traffic through VPN interface

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to set up my own seedbox with rTorrent and I would like to redirect all torrent traffic through my VPN.

I know there is a bunch of QA and HOWTOs on this subject. I've read a lot and came up with this (which isn't working at all...):

## OpenVPN configuration

```
client
dev tun0
proto tcp
remote 173.199.65.63 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/pwd.txt
comp-lzo
verb 1
reneg-sec 0
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem

script-security 2
route-noexec
route-up /etc/openvpn/route_up.sh
```

## /etc/openvpn/route_up.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$dev : $ifconfig_local -> $ifconfig_remote gw: $route_vpn_gateway"
ip route add default via $route_vpn_gateway dev $dev table vpn
ip route flush cache
exit 0
```

## iptables commands issued

```
echo "666 vpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 77 table vpn
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 6880 -j MARK --set-mark 77
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p udp --dport 6880 -j MARK --set-mark 77
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 6881 -j MARK --set-mark 77
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 6881 -j MARK --set-mark 77
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6881 -j MARK --set-mark 77
iptables -t mangle -A INPUT -p udp --dport 6881 -j MARK --set-mark 77
```

6880 and 6881 are the port used by rTorrent, hence the above.

When I run rTorrent with some *CheckMyTorrentIP*-like download, the reported IP address is mine and not my VPN's one.
I thought I was understanding what I read about iptables and stuff, but, obviously, I'm not.

Could someone help me and explain me what I should do ?

Thanks for reading

**EDIT**

The seedbox is built on an Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 64bits distribution.

**EDIT 2**

```
fwoelffel@homeserver:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:6b:c5:f2
          inet addr:192.168.1.17  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe6b:c5f2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1754058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:599118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:2541473428 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:53167571 (53.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:443172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:443172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:58217786 (58.2 MB)  TX bytes:58217786 (58.2 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.30.1.6  P-t-P:10.30.1.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Please specify which OS you're running on your local PC.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `redirect-gateway` option in your openVPN server config, as described [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) (redirects all traffic).

Alternatively, there's the `push "route <ip> <mask>"` option to send traffic to specific IP/ranges through the VPN, as described [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope).

Comment: Isn't this supposed to redirect all the traffic ? I'd juste like to redirect rTorrent's traffic. Anyway. I tried adding push "redirect-gateway tun0" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Yes, it redirects all traffic. If that's not intended, then you'll have to understand first how to identify all rTorrent traffic: by target IP address; by source/target ports; by protocol. Depending on the answer to this, the solutions will vary greatly. The simplest is to route all traffic through the VPN like shown.

Comment: Sure redirecting all traffic is easy and works fine. But what if I want to access to my computer via SSH ? What if I want t use a web ui to add torrents (like ruTorrent) ? At one point I'll have to prevent some connections from being redirected through the VPN interface.

Comment: That is true. You will need to provide more details in your question in order to allow us to provide a more suitable answer, for example: network topology (what IP addresses in your local LAN, and in the VPN); if you're connecting only to the seedbox over the VPN or if you'll be doing internet traffic over it. Lots of possibile answers, depending on your specific details.

Comment: I edited my question to give your more details about my network configuration. The seedbox is in fact a NUC in my local network and I'd like to redirect only it's torrent traffic through its VPN interface.